# Hide foreign id column in an Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's consider the Einstein's Puzzle and these two models:

```
class Pet extends Eloquent
{
    public function pet()
    {
        return hasOne(Man::class)
    }
}

class Man extends Eloquent
{
    public function pet()
    {
        return belongsTo(Pet::class)
    }
}
```

If I want to get all the Pets:

```
Pet::all()->toArray();
```

I'll get for instance:

```
{
    id: 2,
    man: {
        nationality: "German",
        pet_id: 2
    }
    name: "Fish"
}
```

Having the `pet_id` column is irrelevant in that case and I would like to hide it. How?

Comment: Add it to the hidden array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) to get an array version of your Models. This is more flexible in the long run than relying on the toArray method of the model which will not be configurable.

If you still want to use `toArray`, you can simply add the attributes that should not be included to a protected member variable called `$hidden` in each corresponding model (See documentation about [serialization of Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)).

Comment: The `Resouces` would add to much complexity and the `$hidden` does not work on a foreign relation. In my example I would like to hide `pet_id` only when necessary.

Comment: I don't see any complexity in adding a single class to the project. That is precisely what resources have been introduced for. But hey, it is your project, it is all up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Pet extends Eloquent
{
    public function pet()
    {
        return hasOne(Man::class)->select('nationality');
    }
}
```

Comment: This use of `select` is very dangerous because it may clash with other column name. For example if you select `updated_at` you would certainly get an error because this column would exist in both `Man` and `Pet`.

Comment: There will be no clash at all as you will be getting a separate Man object in Pet.

Comment: In my case I had a clash :( `updated_at, ambiguous column name`

Comment: can i see your whole model and the way you wrote your query?